# Mongodb, checking the array of a object/ model before inserting new values

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I am using the following function to register a user for a 'bid'. The user has a bids array, that will take the bid into the array, and save it as part of the user's model. I am using the following function to accomplish this:

```
 // Register client for bid
    module.exports.register = function(info, callback) {
    client_username = info['client_username'];
    bid_id = info['bid_id'];
    bid_title = info['bid_title'];

var query = {username: client_username};
    Client.findOneAndUpdate(
  query,
  {$addToSet: {"bids": {bid_id: bid_id, bid_title: bid_title}}},
  {safe: true, upsert: true},
  callback
    );
}
```

The problem is, I have no check to see if the client already has this bid in their bid's array. I do not know mongoDb and js well enough to check the bids array BEFORE using $addToSet and adding the new bid to the array. However I thought this is what $addToSet is supposed to do.

Does anyone know how I can iterate over the User's bids array to check if the bid I am pushing into the array, already exists in the array? Please see the entire bids model and clients model below..

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');

 // client Schema
 var clientSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    first_name: {
    type: String
    },
    last_name: {
        type: String
    },
    address: [{
        street_address:{type: String},
        city:{type: String},
        state:{type: String},
        zip:{type: String}
    }],
    username: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    bids:[{
        bid_id:{type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId]},
        bid_title: {type:String}
    }]

    });

   var Client = module.exports = mongoose.model('Client', clientSchema);

 module.exports.getClientByUsername = function(username, callback){
     var query = {username: username};
    Client.findOne(query, callback);
 }

  // Register client for bid
 module.exports.register = function(info, callback) {
 client_username = info['client_username'];
 bid_id = info['bid_id'];
 bid_title = info['bid_title'];

var query = {username: client_username};
Client.findOneAndUpdate(
  query,
  {$addToSet: {"bids": {bid_id: bid_id, bid_title: bid_title}}},
  {safe: true, upsert: true},
  callback
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this locally on my MongoDB instance.  While using the FindAndModify(), $AddtoSet only adds a new bid only if it doesn't exist in the Array. If it is present it doesn't do anything. This is the query that I used:

```
db.collection.findAndModify({
    query: {
        "username": "ag102"
    },
    update: {
        $addToSet: {
            "bids": {
                "bid_id": 6,
                "bid_title": "ebay6"
            }
        }
    },
    upsert: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a method to the model, here is a rough cut:

```
 clientSchema.methods.addBid = function (bid, cb) {
    /* Check the array here */
    for (var i = 0; i < this.bids.length; i++){
        if (this.bids[i].title == bid.bid_title) {
            /* do something */
            var error = true;
            cb("Bid already exists",this);
        }
    }
    if(!error){
        this.bids.push({
           "bid_id" : bid.bid_id,
           "bid_title" : bid.bid_title
        });
        cb(undefined,this);
    });
};
```

then you would invoke it like so:

```
var query = {username: client_username};
Client.findOne(query, function(err, client){
    client.addBid({bid_id: bid_id, bid_title: bid_title}, function(err, client){
        if(err) {
            /* do something */
        }else{
            client.save(function(err,client){
                if(err){
                   /* do something */
                }else{
                   /* do something */
                }
            });
         }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use $elemMatch keyword:
https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

For efficiency purposes and presuming you have any control over the schema - I think you'd want to change the above into either an object with hash keys and then make dot notation queries on the bid id.